# How to call function after page fully loaded in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to **invoke a function on particular route after page loaded fully**, like if user logged in and come to main page route first, and it loaded successfully a function will invoke/call by itself.

```
constructor( private router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
   if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) { 
      
     console.log(router.url);
     //function writes here
      
    }
  });
  
  }
```

I am calling this function on main.ts but when user trying to logged in this function invokes why ?

Comment: You’re saying that function is in main.ts..?

Comment: yes it is in main.ts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute function after all views loaded please use ngAfterViewInit() life cycle.

Or else if you want to do in js/ts please use setTimeout() and set time what you want.

```
setTimeout(() => { ... }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This observable is called every time you change the page... try applying a filter on the page you are interested in

```
this.router.events
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
      filter((x): x is NavigationEnd => x instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(x => x.url == 'your url')
    )
   .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need to use a function which calls itself or check after the page loads fully when the user logged in, users should call it in ngOnInit.

```
ngOnInit() {
 //please call your function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According Angular's documentation you can use ngAfterViewInit() for this.
Your component needs to implements  AfterViewInit interface, like this:

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  
ngAfterViewInit() {
    //***Your code here***
  }
}
```

AfterViewInit is a lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has fully initialized a component's view. Define an ngAfterViewInit() method to handle any additional initialization tasks.

Read more in [this link](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit).